# Mousehover from parent to child effect Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building an application in `Vuejs` where I'm having a parent div and child div which on hovering show border of the element.

I implemented this with `@mousehover` and `@mouseleave`, when I hover from parent to child I need to prevent displaying border of parent div and show border of child div.

Below is my code:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="w-full m-20 ml-20 relative bg-indigo-200" @mouseover="toggleEdit('parent')" @mouseleave="toggleEdit()">
        <div class="max-w-[200px] w-full mx-auto bg-white">
            <div @mouseover.stop="toggleEdit('child')" @mouseleave.stop="toggleEdit()" class="w-full relative py-6 flex justify-center">
                <img width="160" height="60" src="https://d3ag9sk63msume.cloudfront.net/project-assets/images/noetic_logo.png" alt="Logo">
                <div v-show="mousechild" class="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full border-2 border-blue-500">
                    <div class="relative w-full h-full">
                        <div class="absolute right-[-30px] flex flex-col">
                            <div class="h-7 w-7 bg-gray-900 flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer">
                                <img src="/project-assets/images/email-template/icons/drag.png" width="20" height="20">
                            </div>
                            <div class="h-7 w-7 bg-gray-900 flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer my-[1px]">
                                <img src="/project-assets/images/email-template/icons/delete.png" width="17" height="17">
                            </div>
                            <div class="h-7 w-7 bg-gray-900 flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer">
                                <img src="/project-assets/images/email-template/icons/clone.png" width="17" height="17">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div v-show="mouseparent" class="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full border-2 border-blue-500">
            <div class="relative w-full h-full">
                <div class="absolute right-[-30px] flex flex-col">
                    <div class="h-7 w-7 bg-gray-900 flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer">
                        <img src="/project-assets/images/email-template/icons/drag.png" width="20" height="20">
                    </div>
                    <div class="h-7 w-7 bg-gray-900 flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer my-[1px]">
                        <img src="/project-assets/images/email-template/icons/delete.png" width="17" height="17">
                    </div>
                    <div class="h-7 w-7 bg-gray-900 flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer">
                        <img src="/project-assets/images/email-template/icons/clone.png" width="17" height="17">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

VueJS part:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      mouseparent: false,
      mousechild: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleEdit(ele) {
      console.log(ele);
      if(ele === 'child') {
        console.log('Event fired: Child')
        this.mouseparent = false;
        this.mousechild = true;
      }
      else if(ele === 'parent') {
        console.log('Event fired: Parent')
        this.mouseparent = true;
        this.mousechild = false;
      }
      if(typeof ele === 'undefined') {
        console.log('Event Fired: all close')
        this.mouseparent = false;
        this.mousechild = false;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

You can have a look to my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b0tq82x5/). Help me out in this.

Answer (score 2):

Your second *big* div which `v-show` upon hovering the `parent` is above your `child` and is *eating* your events:

```html
[...]
</div>
<div v-show="mouseparent" class="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full border-2 border-blue-500">
[...]
```

A quick fix could be to swap the appearance of these two *div*, so that the child *always stays on top*, even if the box is showing on parent hover:

```html
        <div v-show="mouseparent" class="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full border-2 border-blue-500">
            <div class="relative w-full h-full">
                <div class="absolute right-[-30px] flex flex-col">
                    <div class="h-7 w-7 bg-gray-900 flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer">
                        <img src="/project-assets/images/email-template/icons/drag.png" width="20" height="20">
                    </div>
                    <div class="h-7 w-7 bg-gray-900 flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer my-[1px]">
                        <img src="/project-assets/images/email-template/icons/delete.png" width="17" height="17">
                    </div>
                    <div class="h-7 w-7 bg-gray-900 flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer">
                        <img src="/project-assets/images/email-template/icons/clone.png" width="17" height="17">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="max-w-[200px] w-full mx-auto bg-white">
            <div @mouseover.stop="toggleEdit('child')" @mouseleave.stop="toggleEdit()" class="w-full relative py-6 flex justify-center">
                <img width="160" height="60" src="https://d3ag9sk63msume.cloudfront.net/project-assets/images/noetic_logo.png" alt="Logo">
                <div v-show="mousechild" class="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full border-2 border-blue-500">
                    <div class="relative w-full h-full">
                        <div class="absolute right-[-30px] flex flex-col">
                            <div class="h-7 w-7 bg-gray-900 flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer">
                                <img src="/project-assets/images/email-template/icons/drag.png" width="20" height="20">
                            </div>
                            <div class="h-7 w-7 bg-gray-900 flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer my-[1px]">
                                <img src="/project-assets/images/email-template/icons/delete.png" width="17" height="17">
                            </div>
                            <div class="h-7 w-7 bg-gray-900 flex items-center justify-center cursor-pointer">
                                <img src="/project-assets/images/email-template/icons/clone.png" width="17" height="17">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[Tip](https://javascript.info/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave): I would use mouseover/mouseout or mouseenter/mouseleave, but this is my preference

Comment: Hey Matti, thanks for your answer, you gave me the idea. I inserted `absolute` position to my `child` element with some `z-indexing` and that worked very well. This way I don't have to move `child` element outside the `parent` div